# Get dynamically assigned server port?

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

When I call

```java
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.bootstrap.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
  .setListenerPort(0)
  // ...
  .create();
server.start();
```

How do I get the actual port number assigned to the server?

I tried

```java
int port = ((InetSocketAddress) server.getEndpoint().getAddress()).getPort();
```

But that just returned `0`

Answer (score 1):

With Apache HttpCore 5.2, there is a method to get the port of the server:

```java
try (HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
  .setListenerPort(0)
  // ...
  .create()) {
  server.start();
  
  var port = server.getLocalPort();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

HttpComponents hide a lot of the internals and especially what you are looking for, a workaround would be to retrieve a port outside the library and use it:

```java
int port;
try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket()) {
    socket.setReuseAddress(false);
    socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(0));
    port = socket.getLocalPort();
}
        
HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
  .setListenerPort(port)
  // ...
  .create();

server.start();
```

Comment: There is still a possible race condition, between the moment when the ServerSocket is closed, and the moment when you create the HttpServer.